# Function return an array

Tags: c++, arrays, types, return, trailing

I know a function cannot return an array, but this function declaration

```
auto fun(/*...*/) -> int [2]
```

can pass the compilation. Why!?

Comment: Buggy compiler? Which begs the question, which compiler are you using?

Comment: I use MinGW with g++11 rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, a function cannot return a plain array by value.

A declaration with such return type is ill-formed, and if a compiler accepts it without a warning, then the compiler doesn't strictly conform to the standard. It is possibly a bug - or a language extension.

It appears that this bug is reproducible in g++-6.1. If you try to define the function that returns an array, you can see this hilarious error message:

> ```
> error: cannot convert 'int [2]' to 'int [2]' in return
> ```